# Create a drop down using keys of objects within an array

Tags: angularjs

As the title suggests it very clearly, I want to read through an array of objects and create a custom looking drop down. The custom drop down has an anchor title as the default value and a list to show the values. The structure is as below:

```
<div class="sort-select">
<a href="" ng-click="showList =! showList;" ng-init="showList=false;">
Sort By: <span class="info sort-state">Closest Match</span>
</a>
<ul ng-class="{'animate-list':showList}" ng-repeat = "sortByOption in healthResultsInfo.sortBy">
  <li ng-repeat = "(key,value) in sortByOption"><a href="{{value[0]}}">{{key}}</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The JSON structure is as below:

```
"sortBy": [
              {
                  "Relevance": "/shop?ns=relevance",
                  "default": "true",
                  "selected": "true"
              },
              {
                  "Name A-Z": "/shop?ns=relevance",
                  "default": "false",
                  "selected": "true"
              }
          ]
```

As you can see I have tried to get the values, but it is pretty difficult as I need the keys i.e. "Name A-Z" or "relevance" in my drop down options. Also Need to use the default property to select the default value.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you reformat your "sortBy" object to iterate over it easier.

Change your array to an object, and name your keys the drop down option

```
sortBy: {
   Relevance: {
      url: '/shop?ns=relevance',
      default: true,
      selected: true
   },
   'Name A-Z': {
      url: '/shop?ns=relevance',
      default: false,
      selected: true
   }
}
```

You can then use the "orderBy" filter so that the default value is at the top of the list

```
<div class="sort-select">
   <a href="" ng-click="showList =! showList;" ng-init="showList=false;">
      Sort By: <span class="info sort-state">Closest Match</span>
   </a>
   <ul ng-class="{'animate-list':showList}">
      <li ng-repeat = "(key,value) in healthResultsInfo.sortBy | orderBy:'default'">
         <a href="{{value.url}}">{{key}}</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure about the formatting option. Also it is not necessary that the first option is always at the top. Also I need to select the value having default as true in the anchor tag. Sorry but your solution isn't suffice. Thanks for trying though.